NextJS Router Handler / Respond to GET with a Component
I have in my app a path that takes 2 type of requests, for the GET requests I want it to return a React JSX Element/Component, for the POST request I want it to run I process then redirect to another page.
My question is, can a Route Handler return a JSX Component? and if not, do you have a recommendation to achieve my goal?
